# Найти минимальный отрезок прямой, содержащий максимум точек

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Не могу решить задачу с acmp на c++. Кто может помочь? Само условие:

На прямой отмечено N точек. Требуется найти такой отрезок длины L, на котором лежат M из отмеченных точек (M ≥ 2), что величина L/M минимальна. Считается, что точки, совпадающие с одним из концов отрезка, лежат на нем.

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит количество точек N (2 ≤ N ≤ 10000). На второй строке записаны координаты этих точек Xi - целые числа, разделенные пробелами. При этом |Xi| ≤ 30000 и Xi < Xj при i < j.

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите координаты начала и конца найденного отрезка A и B (A < B). Если решений несколько, выведите любое.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int N, a, b, c, d, L = 1000000;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> c;
    for(int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i)
    {
        cin >> d;
        if (d - c == 1)
        {
            cout << c << " " << d << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        if (d - c < L)
        {
            L = d - c;
            a = c;
            b = d;
        }
        c = d;
    }
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

Так как все точки различны, минимум - при расстоянии 1 (сами подумайте, что будет, если добавить еще точку.). Если находим такую пару точек, выводим ее. Если не находим - запоминаем текущий минимум длины, и идем к следующей паре...

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ замечание что минимум `L/M` всегда достигается на паре (и только паре) соседних точек. Это может быть не ясно для читающего.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы его уже добавили :)